# How Do I Add a '_' In The Middle of All Data in the Column of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

eg . I have data like `2008Q1 , 2008Q2 , 2009Q1` in a single column.
I want to give output as `2008_Q1 ,2008_Q2`

```
df['quarter'] = df[:4] + '_' + df[2:]
```

I have  tried this but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you want to add `_` before Q?

Comment: "*I have tried this but it did not work.*" What do you think `df[:4]` and `df[2:]` should evaluate to in this case? Why not something like `df['quarter'].str[:4]` and `df['quarter'].str[2:]` instead?

Comment: @esqew, the second slice should be `df['quarter'].str[4:] ` instead.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `str.replace` here.  Assuming data in the column would always have the format `2022Q1`:

```py
df["quarter"] = df["quarter"].str.replace(r'(?=Q\d$)', '_', regex=True)
```

Comment: Do we really need a regex here? Isn't it just a matter of simply replacing `Q` with `_Q`?

Comment: Yes, that is another option.  You may post as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Nah... I was just curious. :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
df['quarter'] = df.quarter.apply(lambda x: x[:4] + '_' + x[-2:])
```